# EasyChair error message: "It seems that you are not one of the authors of this paper"

Tags: easychair

I am trying to submit a paper for a conference, whose submission process is using EasyChair.org. I get the following error message, even though my name is clearly listed in the PDF version of the paper  I am trying to submit.

[image]

My name is clearly stated in the EasyChair submission form:

[image]

What can cause the error message to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue today and found it was caused by submitting a different emailadress as author than the emailadress you used to sign up your account with. I had submitted my gmail adress when I created the account and tried to use my university emailadress submitting my paper as Author. However, after I used my gmail emailadress for submitting the paper the error message dissapeared.

Hope this helps,
Thomas